# Data not getting written in file [Python]

Tags: python

```
final=open("war.txt","w+")
for line in madList:
  line=line.split('A ')
  dnsreg= line[1]
  print dnsreg
  final.write(dnsreg)
```

While printing `dnsreg` I can see the output, but when I write it to a file, nothing is being written. No syntax error is there either. Any idea?

Comment: Are you closing the file?

Comment: @Diego No Mate . I am not .

Comment: You should -- to flush the buffer and commit the write to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `with` statement in Python when using resources that have to be setup and tear down, like opening and closing of files. Something like:

```
with open("war.txt","w+") as myFile:
    for line in madList:
        line=line.split('A ')
        dnsreg= line[1]
        myFile.write(dnsreg)
```

If you do not want to use `with`, you will have to manually close the file. In that case, you can use the `try...finally` blocks to handle this.

```
try:
    myFile = open("war.txt", "w+")
    for line in madList:
    line=line.split('A ')
    dnsreg= line[1]
    myFile.write(dnsreg)
finally:
    myFile.close()
```

`finally` will  always work, so your file is closed, and changes are written.

Answer (score 3):

The data written to a file is not written immediately, it's kept in a buffer, and large amounts are written at a time so save the writing-to-disk overhead. However, upon closing a file, all the buffered data is flushed to the disk.

So, you can do two things:

1. Call `final.close()` when you are done, or
2. Call `final.flush()` after `final.write()` if you don't want to close the file.

Thanks to @Matt Tanenbaum, a really nice way to handle this in python is to do the writing inside a `with` block:

```
with open("war.txt","w+") as final:
    for line in madList:
        line=line.split('A ')
        dnsreg= line[1]
        print dnsreg
        final.write(dnsreg)
```

Doing this, you'll never have to worry about closing the file! But you may need to flush in case of premature termination of the program (e.g. due to exceptions).